# function in the h:body onload does not work in my JSF page (EDITED)

Tags: jsf

EDITED

I would like to use

```
 <h:body onload="#{myBean.initialize}">
```

but the function initialize() is not called in my JSF page and I don't undertsand why. 
Thanks in advance

The structure of the page  is

```
 <html>
   <h:body onload="#{myBean.initialize}"> 
   <p:layout>
   <ui:composition>
       <ui:define>
           <p:layoutUnit>
                <h:form>
                      <p:panel> 
                            <h:panelGrid>
                              .....
                            </h:panelGrid>
                       </p:panel> 
                  </h:form>
           </p:layoutUnit>
     </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
   </p:layout>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

EDITED

I am using

```
  <p:remoteCommand name="onload" action="#{editUDBean.init}" autoRun="true"/>
```

just after the

```
 <h:form>
```

and this calls the init function

Comment: What version of JSF are you using? And am I correct that `initialize` is the name of a method on your JavaBean named `myBean`?

Comment: yes, you are right for the name

Comment: I am using the 2.1 version

Comment: If you keep changing the question, you prevent everybody from answering effectively.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I should have created another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go right after the `html` tag (or after `head` of course). Almost every tutorial on templating do it this way, see [Mkyong's](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/) one for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found it alos but now, my question has slightly changed because now the function is not called when I want to  load the page

Answer (score 0):

with

```
<h:body onload="">
```

you can trigger a javascript function not a java bean method! You can use onload like this:

```
<h:body onload="alert('onload is called...');">
```